# How to display a queryset object name rather than a queryset object itself in Django?

Tags: python, django

Registered users of my app can create and delete expense tracking sub-accounts. When deleting, they get to pick which account to delete:

[image: Delete Account]

The above image shows the current choices. I would like to display the name of the account, rather than the object which the name is referring to, but how?

forms.py

```
class UdaForm(forms.Form):
# User Deleted Account Form
def __init__(self, *args, user, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.user = user
    self.fields['UDA_name'].queryset = UserMadeAccount.objects.filter(UMA_user=user)

UDA_name = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Account", queryset=UserMadeAccount.objects.all())
```

views.py

```
def user_accounts(request, user_id):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    # Get all accounts of user by matching user_id
    user_made_accounts = specific_umacs(user_id)
    user_data = [i for i in user_made_accounts]

    if "UMA_form_name" in request.POST:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            uma_form = UmaForm(request.POST)
            uda_form = UdaForm(user=request.user)
            if uma_form.is_valid():

                # Adds new user made account to the DB
                add_uma(uma_form, request.user)

                # Get all accounts of user by matching user_id
                user_made_accounts = specific_umacs(user_id)
                user_data = [i for i in user_made_accounts]   
                return render(request, 'user_accounts.html', {"uma_form": uma_form, "uda_form": uda_form, "user_data": user_data})       
                

    if "UDA_name" in request.POST:
        if request.method == 'POST':

            uda_form = UdaForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
            uma_form = UmaForm()

            if uda_form.is_valid():

                # Delete user made account from DB
                delete_uma(uda_form=uda_form, user_obj=request.user)
                
                # Get all accounts of user by matching user_id
                user_made_accounts = specific_umacs(user_id)
                user_data = [i for i in user_made_accounts] 
                return render(request, 'user_accounts.html', {"uma_form": uma_form, "uda_form": uda_form, "user_data": user_data})


    if request.method == 'GET':
        uma_form = UmaForm()
        uda_form = UdaForm(user=request.user)
    else:
        uma_form = UmaForm()
        uda_form = UdaForm(user=request.user)

    return render(request, 'user_accounts.html', {"uma_form": uma_form, "uda_form": uda_form, "user_data": user_data})
else:
    return render(request, 'please_authenticate.html')
```

user_accounts.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block page_content %}

    ...

    <!-- Delete Account Modal -->

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bd-delete_me-modal-lg">Delete Account</button>

    <div class="modal fade bd-delete_me-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Delete one of your accounts</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <form action="" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="col">
                                {{ uda_form.UDA_name|as_crispy_field }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal END -->
    
    ...

    {% endblock page_content %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add  `__str__` method [[doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#str) to your `UserMadeAccount` model

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.field_name
```

> The **str**() method is called whenever you call str() on an object.
> Django uses str(obj) in a number of places. Most notably, to display
> an object in the Django admin site and as the value inserted into a
> template when it displays an object. Thus, you should always return a
> nice, human-readable representation of the model from the **str**()
> method.